# How do I get the touchscreen working on a  VAIO VPCL237FX?

Tags: vaio, touchscreen

Tried searching but no one has this model/series it seems. Anyone know of any working touchscreen drivers for the VAIO VPCL2XXX series desktop all in ones?

Device is NextWindow Voltron

Comment: A good starting point might be http://www.nextwindow.com/nextwindow_support/app_working_under_linux_2.html (top Google result for "NextWindows Voltron Linux").

Comment: What is it's Vendor:Product ids? You can get them from lsusb output. Are they listed here: http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-devices.html ?

Comment: @int_ua I'm having this same issue so I'm going to answer. It shows `1926:0bce` - nextwindow's site doesn't help, I don't think it is picking up from /dev/input/event.

Comment: It's not listed, I think you need to report it: http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-howto.html#report

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.nextwindow.com/nextwindow_support/app_working_under_linux_2.html) page. The file to edit is `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Be sure to have a backup of your original `xorg.conf` before you modify it. This could save your life.

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf-backup-20120517-touchscreen-not-working
```

Then edit the file accordingly to what is written in the above link.

**Remember that editing `xorg.conf` can lead to a broken X Windows System (no GUI) and thus is pretty dangerous if you're not fully comfortable with a bare command line.**

If you should have troubles, you can always:

1. try to remove `xorg.conf` (`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`) and see if Xorg can start a decent X server without it
2. issue a `sudo Xorg -configure` (see [Configuring X11](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x-config.html)). It should create a `xorg.conf.new` in your `/root` directory. Then try to copy it to its original location with `sudo cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
3. read a bit more about [X configuration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) and expecially about [display resolution configuration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) (and in your specific case also about [input device configuration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input)) and try to build yourself your first working `xorg.conf`

Good luck.

EDIT: sorry didn't see the previous comments. Also found a [guy](http://osdir.com/ml/android-x86/2012-03/msg00304.html) that probably did it:

> The touch screen is a NextWindow Voltron 23.6" touchscreen. It works great in windows and with a little configuring I can get it to work in Ubuntu. To get it working in Ubuntu I need to install the [evtouch driver](http://www.conan.de/touchscreen/evtouch.html) for X and then add a few lines to the X config.